# iOS Core Graphic, how to calculate CGAffineTransform(scaleX offset?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, drawrect

While I am learning Core Graphic by [ray wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/409-core-graphics-tutorial-part-3-patterns-and-playgrounds),

one step is to transform UIBezierPath, `var transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)`,

I do not know why the step after is right,which is `transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 15, y: 30)`?

I don't know how the x and y position is calculated out.

By printing the UIBezierPath currentPoint `print(medallionPath.currentPoint)`, I thought the width should be `(x1 - x2) * 0.5`, the height should be `y1 - y2`, I really don't know why it is

`(x: 15, y: 30)`

The whole code is following , tested in Playground

```
let size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 200)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

//Gold colors
let darkGoldColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.5, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1.0)
let midGoldColor = UIColor(red: 0.86, green: 0.73, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)

let medallionPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 8, y: 72, width: 100, height: 100))

print(medallionPath.currentPoint)
//  (108.0, 122.0)
print(medallionPath.bounds)
//  (8.0, 72.0, 100.0, 100.0)
context.saveGState()
medallionPath.addClip()

darkGoldColor.setFill()
medallionPath.fill()

context.restoreGState()
// question
var transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)

// transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 15, y: 30)
medallionPath.lineWidth = 2.0

//apply the transform to the path
medallionPath.apply(transform)
print(medallionPath.currentPoint)
//  (86.4, 97.6)
print(medallionPath.bounds)
//  (6.4, 57.6, 80.0, 80.0)
medallionPath.stroke()


//This code must always be at the end of the playground
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 15, y: 30)
```

is a *translation*.  It shifts the entire path to the right by `15` and down by `30`.  Your question is where did the *magic numbers* `15` and `30` come from.

---

The medallion drawing has a circle with dimensions `100` x `100` starting at position `(8, 72)` as established by this line of code:

```
let medallionPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 8, y: 72, width: 100, height: 100))
```

The code then adds an inner ring by scaling the original path by `0.8`, so it will be an `80 x 80` circle.  So that the center of this smaller ring lines up with the center of the bigger circle, it will need to be offset an additional `10` in both the horizontal and vertical directions.  (The smaller circle is `20` smaller horizontally and vertically, so shifting it by `1/2` of `20` gets it to align properly).  The goal then is to have it positioned at `(18, 82)` with `width: 80, height: 80`.

So, we need to apply a *translation* (a shift) in the X and Y directions, such that when the path is scaled we end up with a path anchored at `(18, 82)`.  The tricky bit is that the scaling gets applied to the shift values, so that has to be accounted for as well.

So, we are starting with an X position of `8`, and we want to apply some translation value `dx` so that when the result is scaled by `0.8` we end up with the value `18`:

```
(8 + dx) * 0.8 = 18
```

solving for `dx`:

```
dx = (18 / 0.8) - 8
dx = 14.5
```

Similarly for Y, we are starting with a Y position of `72` and want to apply a translation `dy` such that when it is scaled by `0.8` we end up with `82`:

```
(72 + dy) * 0.8 = 82
```

solving for `dy`:

```
dy = (82 / 0.8) - 72
dy = 30.5
```

So, the mathematically correct translation is `(14.5, 30.5)`:

```
transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 14.5, y: 30.5)
```

Ray Wenderlich rounded those to `(15, 30)` for some reason known only to them (because the round numbers look better in the code perhaps?).  It's possible that they didn't bother to *do the math* and just tried values until it *looked right*.

Answer (score 1):

here scale is 0.8 means 80% of the current so its x, y, width and height all reduce to 80%
so new scale difference is

```
scaleDifference = ((1/ 0.8) - 1.0) * 100 = 25%
```

now total size difference is 0.25, here inner circle is in centre so centre point does not change so its x and y position change to calculate x and y

here path rect is (8, 72, 100, 100)
so formula to calculate

circle reduce 10% from both side, to keep it in centre needs to increase 10% x and y and reduce 10% in width and height so circle will be in centre

here scale is set to 80% so what ever x and y translation we are giving all will be calculated to 80%, for example if we give translate x = 10 and y = 10 system converts to its 80% so x = 8 and y = 8.

we have to add width difference to the x and y to keep it in centre

width and height is 100 so

```
100 * (scaleDifference / 2.0)
100 * (0.25 / 2.0) = 12.5
```

and due to scaling x and y also reduce to 0.8% so to make it 100% is

```
xDifference = 8 * scaleDifference = 2.0
yDifference = 72 * scaleDifference = 18.0
```

to keep circle in centre we have to add width difference with dx and height difference with dy to get final x and y translation value

```
dx = xDifference + widthDifference = 2.0 + 12.5 = 14.5 
dy = yDifference + heightDifference = 18.0 + 12.5 = 30.5
```